# Displaying image using canvas in Python

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, canvas, python-imaging-library

I am getting errors when I want to display photos using canvas and Tkinter.

The code runs properly but when I added a few lines to display the image I got error like this

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Kacper\PycharmProjects\kosmos\[w budowie]guicosmoscatalog.py", line 60, in show
    photo_display.pack()
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'pack'
```

```
def show(event):
type = clicked.get()

if type == options_list_planets[0]:


    #IMAGE DISPLAYING
    canvas2 = Canvas(root, width = 400, height = 400, bg='#171717', bd = 0, highlightthickness=0, relief='ridge')
    canvas2.pack()
    my_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("Merkury.png"))
    canvas2.place(relx = 0.05, rely = 0.1, relheight = 0.6, relwidth = 0.5)
    photo_display = canvas2.create_image(225, 210, image=my_img)
    photo_display.pack()


    #LINES OF CODE RESPONSIBLE FOR DISPLAYING TEXT (IT WORKS)
    for widget in pierwszy_frame.winfo_children():
        widget.destroy()

    for widget in drugi_frame.winfo_children():
        widget.destroy()

    text_label = tk.Label(pierwszy_frame, text = FULL_MERCURY_DESC)
    text_label.pack()

    #text2_label = tk.Label(drugi_frame, text = MERCURY_FACT)
    #text2_label.pack(side = 'left')
```

Comment: Comment out this photo_display.pack() And remove this too photo_display =

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create an object on a canvas, it's not a widget and can't be treated as a widget. When you call `canvas2.create_image(225, 210, image=my_img)`, tkinter is going to put the image on the canvas at the given location and then return an integer representing the id of the image.

You are then trying to call `pack` on this integer, which gives the error `'int' object has no attribute 'pack'`

The simply solution is to remove that line of code.

You are also making a very common mistake: you are storing the image reference in a local variable. Python will destroy this variable when the function returns. In order for the image to not be destroyed it needs to be saved as a global variable or as an attribute of some object.

For example, you could attach the image to the `canvas2` object like so:

```
canvas2.my_img = my_img
```

This is arguably a design flaw in tkinter, but the solution is simple so it's easy to work around.